# Not able to go from one activity to other activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to use a button to change from Main Activity on android studio to Main Activity 2 and I get the error

```
no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<MainActivity2>)
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                                ^
```

I'm on version 4.1 and I want to assume i'm following an old tutorial or I just missed some punctuation.
This is my code:

```
        buttonPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity2();
            }

            public void openMainActivity2(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: have you included your all activities in manifest.xml ? and also please share your activity2 code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try `getApplicationContext()` or `activity.this` instead of `this`.

I think you are having this issue for "`this`". Cause, I can't see any other issue.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class)
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to give more clarity to Caio's answer, when you use this

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);`

The intent is created in an anonymous inner class i.e. `OnClickListener`. Thus `this` does not refer the instance of your Activity (or Context) as intended. You need to provide the correct context of your class.

Hence , do this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);`

`startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 2):

you should provide the correct context of your class.

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This java code is for the old version, it does not work with android studio's latest version.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivities(intent);
```

here is code for the more recent versions:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMainActivity();
        }

        public void openMainActivity() {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).